# What is problem in this MySQL Query, it is giving error 1064 (42000)?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

the query is

```
CREATE TABLE order(
    order_id int primary key,
    customer_name varchar(30) not null,
    product_name varchar(20) not null,
    date_ordered date,
    quantity int,
    unit_price float,
    phone_no varchar(20)
);
```

the error is :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(
> order_id int primary key,
> customer_name varchar(30) not null,
> ' at line 1

i am using MySQL verson 8.0.32

Comment: `ORDER` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in mysql. Name your table differently .. I'd suggest `orders` because in the end of the day, your table will be a collection of multiple `orders`

Comment: Or enclose your table name in backticks, to make it an identifier (but still you shouldn't use keywords as identifiers).  `CREATE TABLE \`order\` ( ....) `

Answer (score 1):

Because `order` is part of the SQL syntax (to sort queried records using `ORDER BY`) it wont work.

You have to rename your table to something different like for example `orders` then it will work:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
   order_id int primary key,
   customer_name varchar(30) not null,
   product_name varchar(20) not null,
   date_ordered date,
   quantity int,
   unit_price float,
   phone_no varchar(20)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER` is part os mysql syntax just use another name for your table like `orders`:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
order_id int primary key,
customer_name varchar(30) not null,
product_name varchar(20) not null,
date_ordered date,
quantity int,
unit_price float,
phone_no varchar(20)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`order` is a keyword you cannot use it.To know the list of other keywords check the below link
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html